# Can I use parameters to define xsl:key?

Tags: xslt, key, grouping

I'd like to define an xsl:key for grouping. But I would like it to be general, so that i can pass the parameters. Is that possible somehow?
I'd like something like this:

```
<xsl:key name="key1" match="$matchnode" use="$usenode" />
```

But it doesn't work. Can I obtain the same behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 1.0, patterns cannot reference global variables; in XSLT 2.0 they can. So in 2.0 you can use

```
match="*[name()=$matchnode]"
```

assuming this is the intended meaning of your hypothetical syntax. Similarly you can use

```
use="*[name=$usenode]"
```

Of course this isn't completely generic since it requires the use expression to be a child element; it doesn't allow, for example, an attribute. To make it completely dynamic you will need an extension such as saxon:evaluate() which allows XPath expressions to be constructed at run-time from strings.